# Getting more Dependency files while installing Express using npm

Tags: node.js, npm

While installing express using npm on nodejs. getting more dependency on node_modules folder.

```
PS C:\Users\EXCRIN-4\WebstormProjects\FiducialCover> npm install express --save
fiducialcover@1.0.0 C:\Users\EXCRIN-4\WebstormProjects
`-- express@4.13.4
  +-- accepts@1.2.13
  | +-- mime-types@2.1.9
  | | `-- mime-db@1.21.0
  | `-- negotiator@0.5.3
  +-- array-flatten@1.1.1
  +-- content-disposition@0.5.1
  +-- content-type@1.0.1
  +-- cookie@0.1.5
  +-- cookie-signature@1.0.6
  +-- debug@2.2.0
  | `-- ms@0.7.1
  +-- depd@1.1.0
  +-- escape-html@1.0.3
  +-- etag@1.7.0
  +-- finalhandler@0.4.1
  | `-- unpipe@1.0.0
  +-- fresh@0.3.0
  +-- merge-descriptors@1.0.1
  +-- methods@1.1.2
  +-- on-finished@2.3.0
  | `-- ee-first@1.1.1
  +-- parseurl@1.3.1
  +-- path-to-regexp@0.1.7
  +-- proxy-addr@1.0.10
  | +-- forwarded@0.1.0
  | `-- ipaddr.js@1.0.5
  +-- qs@4.0.0
  +-- range-parser@1.0.3
  +-- send@0.13.1
  | +-- destroy@1.0.4
  | +-- http-errors@1.3.1
  | | `-- inherits@2.0.1
  | +-- mime@1.3.4
  | `-- statuses@1.2.1
  +-- serve-static@1.10.2
  +-- type-is@1.6.10
  | `-- media-typer@0.3.0
  +-- utils-merge@1.0.0
  `-- vary@1.0.1

npm WARN fiducialcover@1.0.0 No repository field.
PS C:\Users\EXCRIN-4\WebstormProjects\FiducialCover>
```

The above text is get from command prompt, these are files installed while install express uaing npm...i dont know what to do...

help me to sort out this problem...

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with that, express is also a `nodejs` module, and have its own dependencies, in order to run, npm, downloads all the **dependend** dependencies recursively for each module. If you open the `node_modules/express/package.json` you will get the following part:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "accepts": "~1.2.12",
    "array-flatten": "1.1.1",
    "content-disposition": "0.5.0",
    "content-type": "~1.0.1",
    "cookie": "0.1.3",
    "cookie-signature": "1.0.6",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "depd": "~1.0.1",
    "escape-html": "1.0.2",
    "etag": "~1.7.0",
    "finalhandler": "0.4.0",
    "fresh": "0.3.0",
    "merge-descriptors": "1.0.0",
    "methods": "~1.1.1",
    "on-finished": "~2.3.0",
    "parseurl": "~1.3.0",
    "path-to-regexp": "0.1.7",
    "proxy-addr": "~1.0.8",
    "qs": "4.0.0",
    "range-parser": "~1.0.2",
    "send": "0.13.0",
    "serve-static": "~1.10.0",
    "type-is": "~1.6.6",
    "utils-merge": "1.0.0",
    "vary": "~1.0.1"
 }
```

All of them are dependencies for express that will be downloaded automatically by npm.